# Cannot find type 'T' in scope Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I state that it is a few years that I have not programmed in Swift, some time ago I had created this extension to randomly access the elements of an array but I get the error "Cannot find type 'T' in scope"

```
extension Array {
    func randomElement() -> T {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        return self[index]
    }
}
```

How could I solve? I also tried to put Array  in it but I always get the same error

Comment: Did you mean `Element` instead of `T`? Note that there is a built in function for this now, [func randomElement() -> Element?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement)

Comment: So it is time to break your bonds to your old code and use Swift native `randomElement` method. Note that your implementation will crash if your array is empty. In other words just remove your extension otherwise it will overshadow the native one which returns an optional Element.

Comment: There was a time when `Element` was `T`. It changed sometime c. 2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic on Array is spelled Element not T

You can see that if you jump to the definition of Array:

```
@frozen public struct Array<Element> {
```

So your function needs to return an Element not a T

Comment: This solves the issue (fixes the error) but it is definitely the wrong solution. Besides that the collection might be empty and it should return `Element?` Swift has already its own `randomElement` method.

Comment: Yes, for this particular case, the right solution is to delete the extension altogether because it's no longer required.

Comment: Now it's ok but when I use extension functions I get the error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context